# How to disable scrollbars with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7, scrollbar

I need to lock the browser scrollbars when I show a div that represent a modal window in Internet Explorer 7 only.
Googling I found that I can use `document.body.style.overflow='hidden'` but this doesn't work for IE7. I also tried with `document.body.scroll="no"` which works but only after I mouse over the scrollbar :-S

Does anybody knows a better aproach?

Thansks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To answer your various questions (including that in your other comment), I think you're using the wrong positioning method.

Try `position:fixed`. It's basically the same as `position:absolute` apart from it's relative to the absolute viewport. Ie: if the user scrolls, the item stays in the same place on the screen.

So with this in mind, you can lay out a `position:fixed` overlay. Within that you can have your `position:absolute` (or `fixed` again, if you prefer -- it *shouldn't* make a difference) modal box.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that just solved the problem. I thought I know almost all about CSS until now :-P




Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks I never would have figured this out!  You saved my ass.

Comment: I knew the difference, but I didn't knew when to use each one, until your answer. Thanks.

Comment: Note that "position:fixed" is one of the CSS2 properties that causes trouble in IE6. So this solution will not work if you have to support IE6 in addition to IE7.

Answer (score 2):

Set your modal overlay div to fill the body, so even if they scroll there's nothing they can do because everything is hidden underneath it.

Comment: how do you get the size of the viewport in IE7? I can't get the real size of the body with any of these:
window.innerHeight, document.body.scrollHeight, document.body.offsetHeight, document.documentElement.clientHeight, document.body.clientHeight

The page has a size of around 2000 pixels

Comment: If you use jquery you can just do $("body").width() and $("body").height() to get the body width and height in a cross browser compatible way.

Comment: The application I'm working on uses Prototype, I couldn't find a way with Prototype to get the real height. Height 100% doesn't work either.

I fixed it with position:fixed

Answer (score 0):

you can also hide scrollbars by using `overflow:hidden` so the user wont see the scollbars so it wont get tempted to scoll around:)

Answer (score 0):

This can help you:

```
documentOBJ = {
    /*Width and Height of the avaible viewport, what you'r seeing*/
    window : {
        x : function(){return (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.clientWidth) || window.innerWidth || self.innerWidth || document.body.clientWidth; },
        y : function(){return (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.clientHeight) || window.innerHeight || self.innerHeight || document.body.clientHeight;}
    },

    /*Scroll offset*/ 
    scroll : {
        x : function(){return ( document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollLeft) || window.pageXOffset || self.pageXOffset || document.body.scrollLeft; },
        y : function(){return ( document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop) || window.pageYOffset || self.pageYOffset || document.body.scrollTop; }
    },

    /*Height and width of the total of the xhtml in a page*/
    page : {
        x : function(){return (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollWidth) ? document.documentElement.scrollWidth : (document.body.scrollWidth > document.body.offsetWidth) ? document.body.scrollWidth : document.body.offsetWidth; },
        y : function(){return (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollHeight) ? document.documentElement.scrollHeight : (document.body.scrollHeight > document.body.offsetHeight) ? document.body.scrollHeight : document.body.offsetHeight; }
    },
    pointer : {}
}
```