# Prevent scrolling when videobox is on

Tags: javascript, css, scroll

I'm using videobox to embed streams into my site, and I just discovered that when videobox is "on"- i.e. I clicked on a link that brings it up and dims everything around it- I can still scroll down and see the rest of my (non-dimmed) site. This breaks immersion, and I'd like to disable the scrolling, but only for when the videobox is on.

I have no idea where to start though.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/422028/how-to-disable-scrollbars-with-javascript

Comment: Yeah I played around with the fixed vs. absolute positioning but it doesn't seem to work. Changing it in the videobox css breaks the videobox and I have no desire to make my site constantly non-scrollable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this just with JavaScript, as far as I know, as the `onscroll` event is [not cancelable](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-htmlevents).

You can achieve this by positioning everything in a container `div` with a `height` and `width` of `100%` and disabling overflow on `html` and `body` elements, so you actually get the scrollbars on the container `div`. When your videobox is on, you can turn on an overlay that hides everything behind it (including the scrollbars on the container) and display the videobox on top of it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <title>Prevent scrolling</title>
  <style>
    * { padding: 0; margin: 0; border: 0 }

    html, body {
      height: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    #container {
      position: absolute;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      overflow: auto;
    }

    #large-div {
      background: #aaa;
      height: 5000px;
      width: 5000px;
    }

    #overlay {
      position: absolute;
      background: #fff;
      opacity: 0.7;
      -moz-opacity: 0.7;
      -webkit-opacity: 0.7;
      -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=70)";
      filter: alpha(opacity=70);
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      z-index: 1000;
      display: none;
    }

    #videobox-container {
      position: absolute;
      background: #dd8;
      width: 600px;
      height: 400px;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      margin: -300px 0 0 -200px;
      z-index: 1001;
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="container">
   <div id="large-div"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="overlay"></div>
  <div id="videobox-container"></div>
  <script>
    function showVideoBox() {
      // show both overlay and videobox-container
      document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById("videobox-container").style.display = "block";
    }

    showVideoBox();
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

(You'll have to fiddle a bit with the positions of your elements, but you get the idea.)

Answer (score 0):

The easy solution is to add the css `body{overflow:hidden;}` when the video starts playing and after that remove it.  Also, can you not put the video box in a div tag and set its position to fixed?

Answer (score 0):

in videobox.js

replace line 80

```
    this.overlay.setStyles({'top': window.getScrollTop()+'px', 'height': window.getHeight()+'px'});
```

with this:

```
this.overlay.setStyles({top:-$(window).getScroll().y,height:$(window).getScrollSize().y+$(window).getScroll().y});
```

Essentially this gets the height of the 'y' scroll and rather than just what the screen is showing.