# grey out whole screen including scrollbar

Tags: javascript, css

i want to create a grey out as that of gmail when we try to upload an exe.
the grey out screen should cover the whole screen even the scrollbars, the scrollbars should be visible through it but disabled 
how this can be achieved using javascript and css 
please dont tell me to set the overflow of body to hidden.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent scrolling when videobox is on](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3120712/prevent-scrolling-when-videobox-is-on)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It only works if you wrap your whole page inside a div and set this div to allow scrolling but disallow the body from scrolling (or use iframes).

In gmail, the body has `overflow:hidden`. The scrollbars you see belong to an `iframe` with id `canvas_frame`.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing +1

Answer (score 1):

Did you try looking at the gmail page, with a tool like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), when it's greyed out this way ?

It'll allow you to see exactly how they do it ;-)

Apparently, after a quick look, it seems they're using a `<div>` such as this one :

```
<div class="Kj-JD-Jh" style="opacity: 0.5; width: 1560px; height: 366px;"></div>
```

The interesting thing here is that this `1560px` is bigger than the visible area of my screen : it includes the right scroll bar.

Comment: setting the width that much is not enough there must be some other way

Answer (score 1):

Top level Scrollbars are browser components and not part of the canvas. Thus it is not possible to grey them out. You can only grey out scrollbars that are part of the HTML view.

Otherwise see this

[CSS/JavaScript Use Div to grey out section of page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159914/css-javascript-use-div-to-grey-out-section-of-page)

Comment: then how they did this in gmail